# Lock text Field above or below scrollView while instantiating objects at runtime for Android

Tags: android, scrollview, android-linearlayout, textview

I'm trying to have a locked textField and a ScrollView in an Android app.  I'm trying to do so at runtime but I am missing something.  Whatever object I add to the LinearLayout first is the ONLY one that is shown.  What am I missing?  I am NOT defining anything through a xml layout file.

My main activity is:

package com.example.scrolltest;

import com.example.scrolltest.Draw;
import android.widget.ScrollView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Draw draw;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();

    LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
    ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    int lHeight = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    int lWidth = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;        

    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setText("Test text.  Boom.");

    draw = new Draw(this);
    draw.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    ScrollView scrollView = new ScrollView(this);
    scrollView.addView(draw);

    // add the views to the layout
    ll.addView(scrollView, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(lHeight, lWidth));

    ll.addView(tv, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(lHeight, lWidth));

    setContentView(ll);

}
```

}

Just for grins as the content for the ScrollView is dynamic, and can change anytime, I'll show  a static example of my Draw object:

package com.example.scrolltest;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.view.View;

public class Draw extends View {
    Paint paint = new Paint();

```
public Draw(Context context) {
    super(context);            
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    // Compute the height required to render the view
    // Assume Width will always be MATCH_PARENT.
    int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    int height = 4000 + 50; // Since 3000 is bottom of last Rect to be drawn added and 50 for padding.
    setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
}

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);

    canvas.drawLine(100, 20, 100, 1900, paint);
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
       canvas.drawText("00:00", 10, 10, paint);
       int y = 0;
       int x = 200;
    for(int i = 100; i < 2900; i=i+10){

       paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
       canvas.drawRect(x, i, x+50, i+10, paint);

    if(y == 0){
        y = 1;
        x = 200;
    } else
   {
        y = 0;
        x = 30;
    }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Can you explain why you add the ScrollView to the linear layout and not the inverse,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT` for the width and height for both `TextView` and `ScrollView`. Whichever view you add first will fill the entire LinearLayout leaving no room for the other. Also, I notice that you set the LinearLayout's orientation as horizontal. This will stack the child views `side by side` rather than `on top of each other`. I suggest the following changes:

```
LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
int lHeight = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
int lWidth = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;        

TextView tv = new TextView(this);
tv.setText("Test text.  Boom.");

draw = new Draw(this);
draw.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
ScrollView scrollView = new ScrollView(this);
scrollView.addView(draw);

ll.addView(tv, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(lHeight, lWidth));

// add the views to the layout
ll.addView(scrollView, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(lHeight, lWidth));

setContentView(ll);
```

This will give you the `TextView` on top and `ScrollView` underneath it.

**Edit:**

Another thing, `LayoutParams()` takes arguments in order: (width, height). You are supplying the arguments in the opposite order.

Comment: That still does not render both views.  I only see the textview in this example as well.

Comment: @WildBill Please see the **Edit** above.

Comment: That did it, thanks!  I was sure it was something to do with the layout parameters but as this is ALL new to me I wasn't sure where to start.  When you are deeply in doubt about something, investigating it can be daunting.  Thanks a ton!

Comment: @WildBill ` When you are deeply in doubt about something, investigating it can be daunting`: I know what you mean. Glad I could help.